# Installing the beamer feather theme

Tags: beamer

I am trying to use the `Feather` theme to write a beamer presentation.

The source code in Feathertheme.tex is:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{Feather}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}

\title[]{\textbf{The title}}

\author[Name]{\ttfamily email@domain.com}

\institute[]{}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Content}{}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

%-------------------------------------------------------
\section{Introduction}
%-------------------------------------------------------

\section{Installation}
%-------------------------------------------------------
\subsection{Source files}
\begin{frame}{Installation}{Source files}
%-------------------------------------------------------

\begin{block}{}
The theme contains 4 source files:
  \begin{itemize}
    \item {\tt beamercolorthemeFeather.sty}
    \item {\tt beamerouterthemeFeather.sty}
    \item {\tt beamerinnerthemeFeather.sty}
    \item {\tt beamerthemeFeather.sty}
  \end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

%-------------------------------------------------------
\subsection{Local and Global installation}
\begin{frame}{Installation}{Local and Global installation}
%-------------------------------------------------------
  The theme can be installed for \textbf{local} or \textbf{global} use.
  \pause
  \begin{block}{Local Installation}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Local installation is the simplest way of installing the theme.
    \item You need to placing the 4 source files in the same folder as your presentation. When you download the theme, the 4 theme files are located in the {\tt local} folder.
  \end{itemize}
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{Global Installation}
  \begin{itemize}
     \item If you wish to make the theme globally available, you must put the files in your local latex directory tree. The location of the root of the local directory tree depends on your operating system and the latex distribution.
     \item Detailed steps on how to proceed installation under various operating systems can be found at Beamer documentation.
  \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}


%-------------------------------------------------------
\subsection{Required P
ackages}
\begin{frame}{Installation}{Required Packages}
%-------------------------------------------------------

  For using the Feather Theme you will need the BeaMer class installed and the following 2 packages
  \begin{itemize}
    \item TikZ\footnote{TikZ is a package for creating beautiful graphics. Have a look at these \chref{http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/}{online examples} or the \chref{http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf}{pgf user manual}.}
    \item calc
  \end{itemize}
  Due to the fact that the packages are very common they should be included in your latex distribution in the first place.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The 4 .sty files are located on the local folder of the presentation, and the files 1.pdf and 2.pdf are also in the Feathergraphics folder:[image]

When trying to compile, the following errors occur:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `Feathergraphics/2' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.16 \begin{document}

? 
(Feathertheme.toc) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd")

! LaTeX Error: File `Feathergraphics/2' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.21 \end{frame}

? 
[1] ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\t1cmtt.fd")

! LaTeX Error: File `Feathergraphics/2' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.42 \end{frame}

? 
[2]

! LaTeX Error: File `Feathergraphics/2' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.63 \end{frame}

?
```

Where do I wrong and how could I fix this ?

Comment: Try to move 2.pdf into the graphics folder.

Comment: The files 1.pdf and 2.pdf are already in the Feathergraphics folder.

Comment: OK, as a test: remove `\usetheme{Feather}` for the moment and try if `\includegraphics{Feathergraphics/2}` works

Comment: Can you also please add the complete .log file from your example?

Comment: Here is the complete .log file https://sourceforge.net/p/installing-feather-theme/discussion/general/thread/6a94b404/

Comment: The removing of `\usetheme{Feather}` and the adding of `\includegraphics{Feathergraphics/2}`didn't work.

Comment: I've compiled with `XeLaTeX` and it works finally.

Comment: I've downloaded Feather theme from Overleaf as a .zip. I've opened it in its own folder and compiled FeatherTheme.tex with pdflatex without problems. Files 1 and 2 doesn't exist outside Feathergraphics folder.

Comment: Indeed, it works when compiling with `PDFLaTeX`.